# Lua custom number concatenation

Tags: lua, metadata, lua-table

I have been learning about metatables in Lua and I wanted to implement range operators as in Ruby, so I used this model

```
debug.setmetatable(1, {
    __concat = function(a, b) 
        if a > b then
            error(table.concat({
                "attempt to create a range of values with a",
                "minimum larger than the maximum"
            }, " "))
        elseif a == b then
            return a
        else
            return unpack((function(nStart,nEnd)
                local nTable = {}
                for it = nStart,nEnd do
                    table.insert(nTable, it)
                end
                return nTable
            end)(a, b))
        end
    end
})

print(6 .. 6)
```

But it seems that that it continues to use the default behavior.  Is there any way to get this to work?  I am aware that I could make a function to emulate the behavior and call it with range(n,n2) or similar but that defeats the purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [section 3.4.5](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.5) of the Lua 5.2 manual.

> The string concatenation operator in Lua is denoted by two dots ('..'). *If both operands are strings or numbers, then they are converted to strings according to the rules mentioned in §3.4.2.* Otherwise, the __concat metamethod is called (see §2.4).

If you want to change this behavior, look into [`lvm.c`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lvm.c.html), specifically the [`luaV_concat`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lvm.c.html#luaV_concat) function.

Comment: Thanks, I don't suppose I could change this behavior easily?

Comment: You'd have to look for the underlying work in the code generator that arranges for the effect of `tostring()` near the concatenation. The Lua sources are pretty well commented, but it will not be trivial. The first step would be to eliminate the automatic conversion to string, the second would be to widen use of `__concat`.

Comment: @Hal It's doable, but you'll need to know some C, at least. Please see the addendum to my answer. It may be more effort than its worth though, when you could make a simple `range` function. Syntactic sugar has its costs.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I looked into the index function, but [n](n2) doesn't have quite as much charm and it seems to only be able to return one value.  Thanks for the help, I'll probably end up using a named function.

Comment: I don't suppose you're willing to settle with something like `range(6, 6)`? or how about `r [[6..6]]`? :P